# Run HipHop PHP in Windows

Tags: php, windows, hiphop

I need to run HipHop PHP on a Windows based development environment. Im running Windows 7, I know the version located at [facebook's repository](http://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/) is built for Linux, however I need to run it on Windows.

Some things to consider:

- I don't want to install a Virtual Machine, I have VMWare, but it would be terrible to install it only for that
- No CyWin either...

Anyone can help?

Comment: Don't bother using virtualization. I'm assuming you're running HipHop to speed up your PHP code. If you're going to run it all in a virtual machine, that will probably be more of a performance issue.

Comment: You're right, but Im seeking just to test it... I can compare to the normal response values I receive in the Virtual Machine! or am I too far from the truth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to run HipHop on Windows.

Here's a quote from [Scott MacVicar mailing list post on the subject](http://groups.google.com/group/hiphop-php-dev/msg/02f90ccfd6327c9f):

> We currently have no plans to add
>   Windows support, if someone within the
>   community comes up with a branch or a
>   patch that provides this then we'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for you:

- Try compiling it yourself. If it fails, fix the code so it will compile.
- Consider if there's another way to solve your problem (i.e., other tools than HipHop).

What have you done to solve your problem? Why did you conclude that HipHop was the right solution for your problem? What errors did you bump into when trying to install HipHop? These are such questions that you probably should ask yourself. They might help you to figure out how to solve your problem.