# Run file on Windows which was Compiled using HIPHOP-PHP

Tags: php, hiphop

Is it possible to run the compiled program file on windows?

I have compiled the php script in Linux - ubuntu using HIPHOP-PHP.
Now i want to run that file on windows.

like we use command "compile/program -m daemon -p 8080" in ubuntu. is it possible to run that on windows?

i have search all over the internet but they are saying about entire process from installing hiphop to make it run which is not possible on windows.

But i only want to know about is it possible to run that compiled code in windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run HipHop PHP in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926762/run-hiphop-php-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Not a chance in heck. It's a Linux executable; it won't run on Windows.

You might be able to compile a binary on Windows using HipHop. It would likely be somewhere between a lot and **A LOT** of work to port it, though.

Comment: Thnx. Is it possible to install an Ubuntu emulator on windows and then try HIPHOP-PHP on that emulator.
If yes, can you please suggest me emulator names for that?